# Как сделать чтобы php-fpm в docker-compose подключался к локальному mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, php-fpm

Вот мой файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
fpm:
    build: /images/php
    volumes:
        - /var/www:/var/www
        - /var/www/php-ini:/usr/local/etc/php/custom.d
    environment:
        PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR: "/usr/local/etc/php/custom.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d"
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:9074:9000"
```

Вот Dockerfile с php:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
MAINTAINER PHPtoday.ru <info@phptoday.ru>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    git \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd 

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- 
filename=composer
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Mysql и nginx у меня установлены локально, когда nginx работает с версией php из докера он не подключается к базам данных, ошибка подключения к базе данных, как это омжно исправить?

Comment: Создавайте мост ([bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)), и соединяйтесь по нему.

Comment: Не подскажете как именно это сделать ?